# Edit scheduled task programmatically

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, pinvoke

I need to be able to edit some settings without user interaction, for example this one:
[image: Screenshot]

I already am creating it like that:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

/* ... */

try
{
    ScheduledTasks.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Task");
}
catch (Exception) { }
TaskDefinition TaskProperties = ScheduledTasks.NewTask();
TaskProperties.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Runs background stuff";
TaskProperties.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName, "/background", null));
ScheduledTasks.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Task", TaskProperties);
```

`schtasks.exe` doesn't give a way to edit it, neither does [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/), but the Task Scheduler GUI does, and there is also a [C++ API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381848.aspx). How can I edit these settings? I don't really mind if the solution involves `PInvoke`. Bonus <3 for code snippet.

Note: I do not want a separated XML file to import, since the .exe is supposed to be standalone, and some elements may vary between systems (For example, the location of the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under `Settings` :

```
TaskProperties.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = true;
```

Comment: That's what I get for coding in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Altough their online documentation is not complete, so I have to use HelpViewer to get all the possible stuff, like this.